# How can I get an Entity by ID whilst applying a Hibernate @Filter?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm creating a [library for dealing with temporal entities](https://github.com/joesteel2010/dao-utils) based on the [DAO Fusion](http://opensource.anasoft.com/daofusion-site/index.html) project. One of the issues I've come across is when I query the database for a record by ID the `@Filter` I've defined on my Entity class is ignored.

I've created a filter in my package-info.java as follows:

```java
@FilterDef(name=EFFECTIVITY_FILTER, parameters={@ParamDef(name=EFFECTIVITY_PARAMETER, type=EFFECTIVITY_TYPE)})
```

and a simple entity for use within tests:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column = @Column(name="USER_ID"))
@Filter(name=EFFECTIVITY_FILTER, condition=":effective between start and end")
public class ImmutableUserEntity extends ImmutablePersistentTimestampTemporalEntity<Long> implements UserEntity<Long> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 843453303283850791L;

  private String firstName;
  private String secondName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
  }

  public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
  }
}
```

I've tried the following methods to get by ID

```java
IdentifierLoadAccess<Long> longIdentifierLoadAccess = getSession().byId(Long.class);
longIdentifierLoadAccess.getReference(id);
```

and

```java
getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), id)
```

However the only way I've been able to lookup a record by I and apply the filter is to use a QueryBuilder with an equals predicate for the ID:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<S> criteria = builder.createQuery(targetEntityClass);
    Root<S> root = criteria.from(targetEntityClass);
    criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
    List<S> resultList = getSession().createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    if (resultList.size() > 1) {
      throw new NonUniqueResultException();
    }
    return resultList.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(resultList.get(0));
```

This, however, is not very robust as it is dependant on the Entity's ID field to be named "id".

Is there another, more robust way I can query by ID whilst applying the filter predicate?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. I can get the name of the ID field as follows:

```java
String idField = ((MetamodelImplementor)sessionFactory.getMetamodel()).entityPersister(getEntityClass()).getIdentifierPropertyName();
```

and use the field name in my where clause

```java
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get(idField), id));
```